# Generically get path to any entity

Tags: 7, entities

How can I get the path to an entity whether it's a user, term, node, etc? Of course, I can just figure out the type of the entity and then go through a switch for the proper URL, but that doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`entity_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x) is an option, e.g.

```
$uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
$path = $uri['path']; // $path is e.g. node/1

$uri = entity_uri('taxonomy_term', $term);
$path = $uri['path']; // $path is e.g. taxonomy/term/1
```

It's best to use the API for this, even if hardcoding is an option. It's possible for the URI template for any entity type to be changed using `hook_entity_info_alter`, so you can't always guarantee it's going to be what came out of the box.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!